# Compare two csv files, use the first three columns as identifier, then print common lines

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have two csv files. File 1 has 9861 rows and 4 columns while File 2 has 6037 rows and 5 columns.Here are the files.

[Link of File 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9faET7Bc2o8bzVySkIySjJMSmM/view?usp=sharing)

[Link of File 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9faET7Bc2o8dGRjMTNKZ1dGMlU/view?usp=sharing)

The first three columns are years, months, days respectively.

I want to get the lines in File 2 with the same identifier in File 1 and print this to File 3.

I found this command from some posts here but this only works using one column as identifier:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0;next}; $1 in a {print a[$1]; print}' file1 file2
```

Is there a way to do this using awk or any simpler commands where I can use the first three columns as identifier?

Ill appreciate any help.

Comment: Next time you have a question include a [mcve] which has concise, testable sample input and expected output. See [ask] for more info. Links to large files aren't usually useful, nor will many people even click on them - get your example down to about half a dozen lines per file (i.e. **Minimal**) and people will be far more willing to take a look at it and including the expected output given that input would clear up most requirements ambiguity.

Comment: @EdMorton. Many thanks for the tips. I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3} NR==FNR{a[k];next} k in a' file1 file2
```

Untested of course since you didn't provide any sample input/output.

Answer (score 2):

Just use more columns to make the uniqueness you need:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1, $2, $3] = $0; next}
           $1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3 in a' file1 file2
```

`SUBSEP`
is the subscript separator. It has the default value of "\034", and is used to separate the parts of the indices of a multi-dimensional array. Thus, the expression `foo["A", "B"]` really accesses `foo["A\034B"]`

Comment: Is there a way to isolate the matched output from file2 only?

Comment: Ok no problem. Thanks again for the help.